# How to ignore text values in a sumproduct formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, sumproduct

I'm trying to figure out a way to sum a row based on two cells in the same row. I tried to use a sumproduct but I'm getting an error as I have text in my sum range. Any way to ignore the text to just sum the numbers? Maybe sumproduct isn't even the best way to go about this? I'm trying to get the top section to work but finding the month, the total for each section, and sum the corresponding row. Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LnT2iYA7UCkQeB57ow2IASQkhcpyVxO917Chh2M3YuQ/edit#gid=0

`=sumproduct(($C$9:$E$56)*($A$9:$A$56=C$1)*($B$9:$B$56=$B2))`

I expected that formula to sum the row being referenced by the corresponding month and staff total line.

Comment: the linked sheet is private so we can't access it.

Comment: whoops!  Its public now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) inside the `SUMPRODUCT`

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR($C$9:$E$56*($A$9:$A$56=C$1)*($B$9:$B$56=$B2)))
```

You could also do it with a single formula in C2 using the [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) function (see tab 'z' for a demo):

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(C1:E1&B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(C9:E56*(A9:A56&B9:B56=x))))))
```

Comment: The iferror worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Try wrapping your current formula conditions with `iferror()` as such:*

```js
=sumproduct(iferror(--$C$9:$E$56,0)*($A$9:$A$56=C$1)*($B$9:$B$56=$B2))
```

***OR***

```js
=sumproduct(iferror(($C$9:$E$56)*($A$9:$A$56=C$1)*($B$9:$B$56=$B2)))
```